# datetime difference with php

Tags: php, datetime, time, subtraction

I've viewed a few posts on this, but I'm still a bit confused on how it works.

I want to compare 2 times. The first time is the time NOW and the second time is a datetime coming from the database. I'm able to get the difference in days, months and years, but when I try to get the mins and seconds, the numbers do not seem correct.

Here is my code for getting the time in minutes and seconds:

```
$date1 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$date2 = $blah['datetime']; //the variable here is in dateTime format coming from the database
$diff = abs(strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1)); //Does this give the seconds?
$mins = floor($diff / 60);
```

So far minutes it's returning something like 560, even though I added that row (in the database to a table) a minute ago. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding something, or missing something. Let me know if you want me to clarify anything. Thanks!

Comment: Show us the values of `$date1` and `$date2`.

Comment: Both $date1 and $date2 have the same format date('Y-m-d H:i:s'). $date1 is the date now (current time) and the $date2 is the same date format that was stored in the past. Do you need to know the exact date and time?

Comment: Nonetheless, the dates are as follows: $date1 = 2013-05-11 21:55:19
$date2 = 2013-05-11 12:49:12

Comment: It would appear to me that there are 560 minutes between these two time stamps...

Comment: Yes..The code that I showed above gave me about the same number as you  mentioned. Someone else posted earlier that $diff is giving me the milliseconds, so I tried dividing it by 1000, but then the number in minutes gave me 0.

Comment: Hint: *timezone settings!*

Comment: lol you're tickling my brain

Comment: Take look at http://PHP.net/datetime

Comment: @tickerll Was my answer of any use to you?

Comment: @vascowhite Thanks for checking back, I took a look at PHP's datetime functions and I'm not quite certain where I should begin. EDIT: I didn't realize you edited your last answer. I will try it out

Answer (score 0):

This calculation is quite easy with PHP's [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) and [DateInterval](http://php.net/dateinterval) classes.

```
$date1 = new \DateTime();
$date2 = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $blah['datetime']);
$diff = $date1->diff($date2); // $diff is an Instance of DateInterval

$mins = ($diff->days * 60 * 24) + ($diff->h * 60) + $diff->i;
```